# What happens when a prototype function calls a regular function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Say I have

```
myObject.prototype.myFunction = function()
{
    myOtherFunction();
}

function myOtherFunction()
{
    // ...
}
```

Is it bad to do this, what are the ramifications, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What happens when a prototype function calls a regular function in javascript?

The function gets called :)

There is nothing wrong about doing this. This other function is just not part of the object. This is no different than calling anyother method from your prototype function. For example, I don't think you would think twice about this code:

```
myObject.prototype.myFunction = function()
{
    alert(Math.pow(2,5));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not bad, it's standard.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything wrong with this.  There can be cases where a method is defined in the global scope that you will need to use from a class.  Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see why this would be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

A prototype function is not distinct from a "regular" function.

The only difference is that the function is inherited by instances of the prototyped object. Still, this doesn't make a prototype function any more special than other functions.